# Change in node_modules doesn't take effect

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I have a JS project which installs many modules under node_modules directory. The project is configured to be bundled using webpack. When I make changes to index.js at the root of the project, and then issue "webpack" command, I see the changes. However, when I make a change to a file in a module under node_modules, and then issue "webpack" command, I don't see the changes. Do you have any idea why?

The project is Monaco Editor samples, browser-esm-webpack: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/tree/master/browser-esm-webpack

PS: I have already seen comments regarding not to change modules under node_modules. I made sure that all my installations are local and I am not planning to publish this project since it is customized for a very specific need.

Comment: You really should include at least your webpack configuration in your question. Could be that your loaders are excluding the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Thanks @axm__, I actually solved my problem. I needed to edit the modules source in a separate place and then install it back as a dependency.